# How to scroll to line in QML TextArea?

Tags: scroll, qml, textarea

How can I scroll to a particular line in a multiline, rich text QML TextArea?  There is [positionToRectangle](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-textedit.html#positionToRectangle-method) but that only accepts a position as an int which doesn't seem suitable for multiline text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest trying to calculate the position based on the line number multiplied by line height. You can calculate height of one line like this:

`(textArea.implicitHeight - 2 * textArea.textMargin) / textArea.lineCount`

This might help you to use `positionToRectangle`.

edit: as an afterthought, have you tried setting `cursorPosition`?

Comment: Setting the `cursorPosition` has the same problem, you need to know the `position`. But your idea in general makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A `TextArea` is not scrollable by itself (cf [Scrollable TextArea](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-textarea.html#scrollable-textarea)):

> If you want to make a TextArea scrollable, [...] it can be placed inside a ScrollView.

Then you just have to set the `contentY` of your `contentItem`:

```
ScrollView {
    id: view
    width: parent.width
    height: 60
    TextArea  {
        text: "A\nB\nC\nD\nE\nF\nG\nH\nI\nJ\nK\nL"
    }
}

Button {
    text: "scroll"
    onClicked: view.contentItem.contentY += 10
}
```

Comment: The problem is to figure out which `contentY` to scroll!

Comment: Indeed. Then you can combine with a calculation similar to MarPan answer to assign the correct `contentY` value based on `lineCount` and `contentHeight`